# new nar file installed but the processor version is not upgraded

Tags: version, apache-nifi

I have a customized processor in nifi:
MyScrollElasticSearchHttp, the version is v1.0
I fixed something in the customized processor and build a nar file: MyScrollESHttp.nar which contains MyScrollElasticSearchHttp, version is v2.0

I was hoping after I put MyScrollESHttp.nar into lib
I'd see all customizer's processor MyScrollElasticSearchHttp will be automatically upgraded to v2.0.
However, That automatic upgrade does not happen. The processor in the flow is still V1.0.
If I try to add MyScrollElasticSearchHttp, I do see both versions are available.

I tried a few things to remove all *ElasticSearch* nar files and only kept mine somehow I still see older version.
I also cleaned up a sub directories lib/extensions/unpack...and remove all *elastic* nar (keep mine only) but the older version is still there.

Is there a way to automatically upgrade the processor to the newer version in nifi?

Is there a convenient way to list the contents of a nar file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't ever put anything in the "lib" directory. If you have a NAR in "lib_community" dir, say mystuff-1.nar, and then put an updated NAR, say mystuff-2.nar, into "extensions" dir, you would see both versions. NiFi would leave the current processors at v1. I believe the same would hold true if both versions of the NAR are both in lib_community. If you remove the old version of NAR (v1) but leave the new NAR(v2), it should automatically upgrade the processers from v1 to v2 on restarting NiFi.

Here is something on creating custom directories instead of using "lib": https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Steps-to-deploy-custom-Nars/td-p/212905

Note: "lib_community" might be our organization's convention (not sure). "extensions" exists as of NiFi 1.9.0. If it looks like nothing is happening in the nifi-app.log, then restart it.

To see the contents, I either check in the work/nar/extensions for the unpacked nar, or I use unzip to unzip the nar and look at it that way.

Here is a fairly good description of what NiFi does with multiple versions: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Nifi-autoload-custom-nar-how-to-reload-the-nar-with-changes/td-p/377197